# Python does not find custom PyQt5

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt5, custom-build

As the offical pyqt5-installation in the ubuntu repositories seem to lack support for QtQuick, I tried to install pyqt5 from source. The installation itself seems to work correctly, but when running a python script that uses PyQt5, python complains that it cannot find that PyQt.

After building sip 4.15.5, I downloaded PyQt5.2. It should be compatible to my version of Qt (output of `qmake --version`):

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.0 in /opt/qt5.1.1/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib
```

I ran

The output of configure.py of pyqt can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Mitmischer/8677889 .

The installation output of pyqt can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Mitmischer/8677780 .

After `sudo make install`, I can see a folder `PyQt5` in `/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages` which is quite nice. However, if I run cat `PyQt5/__init__.py`, there is no actual code inside:

```
# Copyright (c) 2014 Riverbank Computing Limited <info@riverbankcomputing.com>
# 
# This file is part of PyQt5.
# 
# This file may be used under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# version 3.0 as published by the Free Software Foundation and appearing in
# the file LICENSE included in the packaging of this file.  Please review the
# following information to ensure the GNU General Public License version 3.0
# requirements will be met: http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html.
# 
# If you do not wish to use this file under the terms of the GPL version 3.0
# then you may purchase a commercial license.  For more information contact
# info@riverbankcomputing.com.
# 
# This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE
# WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Yep, that's all what is inside that file. I don't know whether it's supposed to be that way, but it looks strange to me. Furthermore (`ls PyQt5`):

```
__init__.py               QtCore.so      QtGui.so         QtMultimediaWidgets.so  QtPositioning.so   QtQuick.so       Qt.so     QtTest.so     QtX11Extras.so
_QOpenGLFunctions_2_0.so  QtDBus.so      QtHelp.so        QtNetwork.so            QtPrintSupport.so  QtSensors.so     QtSql.so  QtWebKit.so   QtXmlPatterns.so
QtBluetooth.so            QtDesigner.so  QtMultimedia.so  QtOpenGL.so             QtQml.so           QtSerialPort.so  QtSvg.so  QtWidgets.so  uic/
```

Doesn't look that pythonic.

As suggested elsewhere, I (hopefully) set my pythonpath appropriately:

```
> echo $PYTHONPATH 
/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/
```

Now, if I start an interactive `python3.3`-session (or a script), PyQt5 cannot be found:

```
Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
>>>
```

Has anyone else tried to install PyQt5 from source? What can I do to make PyQt work?

Comment: It seems that the installation was successful. The `__init__.py` should be empty: `PyQt5` is just a namespace. The `*.so` files are all the compiled extension modules. The only thing I can think of, is that you are somehow running the "wrong" python3.3 - do you have more than one installed?

Comment: @ekhumoro: I guess not : `which -a python3.3` just shows `/usr/bin/python3.3`

Comment: Curious. As an experiment, open an new interactive session, then do `os.chdir('/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages')` and try importing PyQt5.

Comment: It might also be useful if you showed the output of `sys.path`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Mea culpa! I thought I had set PYTHONPATH correctly, but I forgot to export that variable (Still not used to fish-shell). Having said that, after running `set -U PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages` , it just works! However, I don't like to set PYTHONPATH every time on login ( I mean, the version from the Ubuntu repositories works as well and I don't think it set PYTHONPATH) - Do you know of another way to make python aware of my pyqt-installation? Thank you for your time.

Comment: I set my PYTHONPATH in `~./bashrc`. For fish-shell, you probably need to consult [this](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#initialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probrably messed PYTHONPATH in someway.

I have successfully built, installed and used PyQT using virtual environment. So here is how to install it using virtualenv. There are tons of tutorals, so please read about it.

So install `python-virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper` (at least that's what they are called on Debian).

```
mkvirtualenv -p /path/to/python3.3 name 
workon name
cd PyQtSource
configure 
make 
make install
```

To use this enviorment do:

```
workon name
python
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did _not_ set PYTHONPATH correctly.